# css not applying to next applicaiton

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mern

i have this h5 with className  that is useraccount and i have provided it like styles.useraccount but some elements get applied css while some dont

**html**

```
  <h5 className={styles.useraccount} >User Accounts</h5>
```

**here is css styling**

```
.useraccount {
             
    font-family:"Nunito";
   font-style:"normal";
   font-weight:"bold";
   color:"#FFFFFF";
   font-size:"24px";
   line-height:"36px";
   top:"8px";
   
   left:"40px";
  }
```

Comment: "Some elements"? Do you mean some style rules, or some headings? It would help if you could provide a more complete example in a working snippet.

Comment: Without more context there's not much to say

Comment: @pilchard  , i have home.module.css where as i mentioned added the css and    <h5 className={styles.useraccount} >User Accounts</h5>  this code is in my page called user .

Comment: Add that to the question, as well as how you are importing your css module and the return statement of your component.